# React Native - setState from array

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm trying `create-react-native-app` for the first time and I want to change text on varying time intervals. But my code only gives me the last item of the array.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const blinkText = [
  {
    text: "A",
    time: 500,
  },
  {
    text: "B",
    time: 1000,
  },
  {
    text: "C",
    time: 1000,
  },
  ];


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      blinkText.map(value => this.setState(value))
    }, this.state.time);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }


  render() {
   return(
    <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```

I know I have my problem at `componentDidMount()` but I could not think of a way. Please take a look at my code and modify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
componentDidMount(){
    blinkText.map(e => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                    text: [...prevState.text, e]
                });
            );
        }, e.time);
    });
}
```

Note that, `this.stat.text` is an array, so you should render it inside your `render()` method by applying `map()`

Example:

```
{ this.state.text.map((e, i) => {
   return (
     <Text key={i}>{e}</Text>
   );
})}
```